# Шаблон регулярного выражения для поиска полного совпадения со строкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Нужна помощь с регулярным выражением, а точнее с составлением шаблона, для поиска полного совпадения со строкой.

Пример:

```py
import re

word = input()
with open('first.txt', 'r') as file1:
  line = file1.read()
  if re.search(word, line): #т.к.ищется первое вхождение, то нужно как - то настроить шаблон, и я не понимаю как это сделать
    print('слово найдено')
```

Comment: Слово для поиска, это word?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, не, word пользователь вводит слово

Comment: Я так понял, вам нужно сравнить вводимое слово со строкой из txt?

Comment: Дайте пример вводимых и выводимых данных

Comment: да, всё верно.
как у меня работает (без шаблона):
содержимое файла:
кот,
китобой
ввод:
кит
вывод:
слово найдено

Comment: а должно быть наоборот, что его нет, а для этого нужен шаблон

Comment: @Let'ssayPie что думаешь?

Comment: Тебе именно строгое соответствие нужно?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Comment: @ReinRaus обязательно ознакомлюсь, спасибо

Comment: А зачем для ПОЛНОГО совпадения использовать  регулярное выражение?

Comment: так удобнее, на мой взгляд

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно ли я вас понял, с учетом строгого соответствия?

```
import re

word = input()
with open('first.txt', 'r') as file1: 
    for line in file1.readlines():
        if re.findall('^' + word + '$', line):
            print('Cлово найдено')
        else: 
            print('Не найдено')
```

Comment: Да, спасибо огромнейшее! Только добавь, пожалуйста, подправь, код, я Вас немного запутал.
`import re

word = input()
with open('first.txt', 'r') as file1:
    for line in file1.readlines():
        if re.findall(r'^' + word + '$', line):
            print('Cлово найдено')
        else:
            print('Не найдено')`
чтоб до конца файла шло)
Ещё раз, огромнейшее спасибо!

Comment: По идеи, `if re.findall('^' + word + '$', line):` полностью заменяется `if re.match(word, line):`

Comment: @gil9red, хм, соглашусь

Comment: По идее или нет, `re.match` не ищет полного совпадения со строкой (только в её начале), а вот `re.fullmatch` — да. И тут лучше использовать не `if re.findall('^' + word + '$', line)`, а `if re.search('^' + word + '$', line)` или `if re.match(word + '$', line)`.